# DE Power Series solution centered at $0$ but DE not defined at $0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I took a test in which I was asked to give a solution in terms of a power series for the equation:
$$x^2y''(x)-xy'(x)+(1-x)y(x)=0,~~~~~~~x>0.$$

At first I began to work on a power series centered at $0$ but then realised that the function is not defined at $0$. So I centered the solution at $x_0\in(0,\infty)$. My question is, even if I can give a power series around $0$ as a solution, is this solution valid? My guess is that it is not because $0$ is not even in the radius of convergence of the solution.

I appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0$ is a **regular singular point** of this differential equation.  The 
indicial equation is $r^2 - 2 r + 1 = 0$, so there is a double indicial root $r=1$.  This means there will indeed be a series solution of the form
$$ y(x) = x + \sum_{j=2}^\infty a_j x^j $$
as well as one containing logarithmic terms
$$ y(x) = x \log(x) + \sum_{j=2}^\infty (a_j \log(x) + b_j) x^j $$
The first is valid for all $x$ in some interval around $0$ (including $0$ itself), the second in an interval $0 < x < R$.

Comment: So it doesn't matter whether initially the DE is not defined at a point, if the point singular and regular, then we use Frobenius method and that's it?

Comment: That's basically it. The series  is designed to be a solution **around**, but not necessarily at, the point $x_0$ (or on one side of it in the case of logarithmic terms).